# Wordpress post Loop not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement

I'm using a theme that uses the blog page to display all of its content on the blog page rather than an excerpt and then when i click into the post i want to show the whole content.

I'm using the following code:

```
$postId = get_the_ID();
        $ex = the_excerpt();

        if($postId == 19){

            echo $ex;


        }

        else{

            echo $content;

        }
```

The blog page is located at post =19

I would expect only the excerpt to show on the blog page and the content to show on the post page.  However both show. Also it doesnt matter if i change the number 19 in my if statement as the same happens. Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

edit made changes, screen shots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

functions such as `the_excerpt()` are only available inside the loop or after you call the function the_post()

You may want to display only the except in your index.php

```
while (has_posts()) {
    the_post();

    the_excerpt();
}
```

In your single.php you may want to display the whole content

```
if(has_posts()) {
    the_post();

    the_content();
}
```

Comment: @jrarama, `the_content() ` is itself used to output the content so it does not require the `echo the_content();`. same is for `the_excerpt()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `the_excerpt();` inside the condition means where you want to display the excerpt but in case you want to get value of excerpt but does not want to display it directly then you have to use `get_the_excerpt();` so you need to change

```
$ex = the_excerpt(); 

to

 $ex = get_the_excerpt();
```

And same is the case with `the_content()`

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use $postId = get_queried_object_id(); instead of $postId = get_the_ID();
```

Comment: Thank you mate, that works great on the blog page, however the individual blog pages now show the excerpt and the content.

Comment: Can you send the screenshot?